# What is the good way to implement recursive subdocument array in mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

The purpose is to go from this :

```
    const team1 = {
        members: [
            {
                role: 'Employee',
                name: 'A',
            },
            {
                role: 'Leader',
                name: 'B',
                subs: [
                    {
                        role: 'Employee',
                        name: 'C'
                    },
                    {
                        role: 'Leader',
                        name: 'D',
                        subs: [
                            {
                                role: 'Employee',
                                name: 'E'
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    };
```

to this :

```
{"_id":"5b9692afdbc5ae16048dc5ec","members":[{"_id":"5b9692afdbc5ae16048dc5f1","role":"Employee","name":"A"},{"_id":"5b9692afdbc5ae16048dc5ed","role":"Leader","name":"B","subs":[{"_id":"5b9692afdbc5ae16048dc5f0","role":"Employee","name":"C"},{"_id":"5b9692afdbc5ae16048dc5ee","role":"Leader","name":"D","subs":[{"_id":"5b9692afdbc5ae16048dc5ef","role":"Employee","name":"E"}]}]}],"__v":0}
```

In one line:

```
const data = new Team(team1);
data.save();
```

I achieved it by doing this configuration:

```
    const HumanSchema = new Schema({
        name: String,
    }, { discriminatorKey: 'role'});
    const EmployeeSchema = new Schema({}, { discriminatorKey: 'role'});
    const LeaderSchema = new Schema({subs: [HumanSchema]}, { discriminatorKey: 'role'});
    const TeamSchema = new Schema({
        members: [HumanSchema]
    }, {discriminatorKey: 'role'});
    TeamSchema.path('members').discriminator('Employee', EmployeeSchema);
    TeamSchema.path('members').discriminator('Leader', LeaderSchema);
    LeaderSchema.path('subs').discriminator('Employee', EmployeeSchema);
    LeaderSchema.path('subs').discriminator('Leader', LeaderSchema);
```

So, first, is it the best way to do it? Or is there any other easy way to have the same result?

Secondly, let's assume we want to build another team from a part of the first one
like:

```
const data = new Team(team1);
const res = data.save();
const team2 = res.members[1].subs; 
/* which is     [{"_id":"5b9692afdbc5ae16048dc5f0","role":"Employee","name":"C"},{"_id":"5b9692afdbc5ae16048dc5ee","role":"Leader","name":"D","subs":[{"_id":"5b9692afdbc5ae16048dc5ef","role":"Employee","name":"E"}]}] */
const data2 = new Team(team2);
```

And then an employee wants to change his/her name, 
How can I update it in both team from one request?

If I can't I guess I have to change my schema configuration, what would be best? (keeping in mind I need to create the team in one request from a json)

Comment: Are you trying to change the name of the employee inside sub array?

Comment: @mehta-rohan Yes